# disabling all mode changes

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I use `vim` as a pager with [`vimpager`](http://github.com/rkitover/vimpager/) and a [script](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager/issues/212#issuecomment-281179950) to change between pager and full `vim` mode.

But pressing `i`, `a`, etc change the mode while paging, which I want to prevent from happening.

I tried `map i <Nop>` and it works, but then I cannot restore the original behaviour, when switching to full `vim` mode.

Comment: From the vimpager github page: "To use a different vimrc with vimpager, put your settings into a ~/.vimpagerrc or ~/.vim/vimpagerrc or a file pointed to by the VIMPAGER_RC environment variable."

Does it work to put your map commands there ?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. I put the `map` commands after `HideCursorInLessMode()` and `RestoreCursor()` in `~/.vimrc`, which should work the same as the alternative `rc` files you mention.

Answer (score 1):

For my configuration for using Vim as a MANPAGER, I [`set nomodifiable`](https://github.com/murukeshm/vim-manpager/blob/master/ftplugin/man.vim#L53). With that, Vim doesn't allow me to enter an editing mode:

```
E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off
```

This doesn't block visual mode, of course, which makes it all the more convenient.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant **all** modes. I have `mouse` enabled, so selecting text changes the mode. I wouldn't mind mapping the relevant key bindings to `<Nop>`, but I still couldn't figure out how to get the original behaviour back.

Comment: @1.61803 what do you mean by "switching to full Vim mode" here?

Comment: You can toggle `vimpager`'s default `less` mode with `,v` to what I called 'full `vim` mode', that is as if you opened a file with `vim foobar`.

Comment: I tried `nomodifiable` in the script I referenced above, but then I'm not able to restore the normal behaviour with `modifiable` (in the function `RestoreCursor()`). `Vim` documentation doesn't say much about this option neither. Could you check that up?